# Best/Cheapest way to buy five microsoft office licences (2010 ed.)s

Tags: licensing

Can anyone give me some hints on the best/cheapest way to buy five Microsoft office licences (2010 ed.) for a charity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might check out TechSoup (http://home.techsoup.org/pages/default.aspx).  They do licenses for a large variety of things for very cheap.  It is better for volume purchasing, though, since they limit how many buys you can make in a given period.

Answer (score 3):

I have used CDWG.com for Charity and Academic licensing of Microsoft products in the past.

Here are 2 Office 2010 products that might be useful:

[Microsoft Office Standard 2010 - license](http://www.cdwg.com/shop/products/default.aspx?EDC=2075883)

[Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010 - license](http://www.cdwg.com/shop/products/default.aspx?EDC=2075914)

When you buy these, they(MS/CDWG) email you an Authorization Number and an Order number. You will create an account on the [Volume Licensing Service Center website](https://www.microsoft.com/licensing/servicecenter/). From there, you can download the relevant ISO images and obtain your Product Key.

You will get a single product key to use for all of your licenses. If you need to buy more licenses in the future, you just add the order number, and your license key stays the same.

---

In the future, if you ever need other Microsoft products, searching with "Charity" or "Academic" and "Open" (Or whatever licensing program you are using. I find Open very easy, but others might be cheaper/better.) will show you the available options. When you make other purchases and register them with the VLSC, all of your downloads and license keys will be in the same place.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a charity, have you tried contacting the local Microsoft folks?

Comment: Not yet, I was going to call them in the morning, there are a few websites which seem to offer good deals but I thought I'd check here first.

Comment: Be very careful with some of the web sites offering deals too good to even sound true. Some of them are selling "less-than-legal" distributions (e.g. wrong country, etc.). Some of them actually pop up as preferred/high search results.

Comment: Ah, good advice, I'll take care to check their credentials - thanks for the heads up!

Comment: No problem and good luck with the endeavors.